# Binding to interface only if it is the needed type (use fallback otherwise)?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I have the following property in my ViewModel

```
public IEquipment Equipment
{
    get
    {
        return equipment;
    }
    set
    {
        if (equipment != value)
        {
            equipment = value;
            InvokePropertyChanged("Equipment");
        }
    }
}
```

This item itself has a `bool` property, which is bound to an `Ellipse` in my View, which I want to use as a indicator item:

```
<Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Equipment.IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, FallbackValue=DarkGray}" Margin="1"/>
```

The `BoolToColorConverter` simply converts the color to either green (`true`) or red (`false`). During runtime `Equipment` can be an instance of one of two class types which inherit from `IEquipment`. Only one of them has the `IsAvailable` property. In practice this works fine, I get eighter my red or green color...or a gray one, in case the other type of equipment is active.

Problem is, that each time the GUI updates, the following warning gets output:

> System.Windows.Data Warning: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'IsAvailable' property not found on 'object'

How can I avoid this issue? Basically I want to bind to this property only if it is of the correct type.
I can think of two solutions, which I'm not particularly fond of:

1. Simply add the `IsAvailable` property to the other type and set it to null (`BoolToColorConverter` can handle null values and returns dark grey): This might be ok for a simple `bool`, but in my actual case there are other items, which are quite class specific.
2. Do the databinding in the code-behind: This might work. Using an event like `Loaded` on startup to set the binding manually at runtime based on the type. However, this might be troublesome for debugging later, because all other Bindings in the project happen directly in the xaml file. Additionally, `Equipment` might change during the lifetime of the ViewModel, so I would have to somehow track it.

Comment: You can add something like `IsEquipmentAvailable` property right into model itself. There in getter you check if Equipment has IsAvailable property (preferrably using some interface and not via reflection). Then you bind directly to this property and not to `Equipment.IsAvailable`.

Comment: @Evk Thank you, this was my first idea as well, however without a setter there is nu update to the GUI. Implementing a setter and tracking changes would mean dependencies I don't want to have...

Comment: You should not need a setter if you will: 1. Call `InvokePropertyChanged("IsEquipmentAvailable")` from setter of `Equipment`  2. Subscribe to propertychanged of Equipment in its setter and do the same there. A bit of code but probably easier than redesign with data templates.

Comment: @Evk Ha, of course! Thank you haven't thought of it... Only thing bugging me a bit is the same as the first point in my OP: If it is not just a simple bool but lists, objects,..etc. I suddenly have unrelated stuff in my ViewModel. So I guess the solution is fine, but depends on the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xaml doesn't bind to interfaces, it binds to concrete types.

If your types have different properties, then you need different xaml to bind them.

Use [DataTemplates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) to specify different xaml for displaying each type.

Comment: It very much depends on exactly what you're trying to do. For instance, you might be able to wrap your IEquipment objects in an EquipmentViewModel that always has an IsAvailable property, and handles the differences in its getter. Your _"there are other items, which are quite class specific."_ quote made me think there were more fundamental differences with what you were displaying.

Comment: Yep, as mentioned above in the comments with Evk we discussed the same. However, in my case I'll have to use templates, since I have a few different properties.

Answer (score 1):

If the properties on your derivatives of `IEquipment` (here `Equipment` and `OtherEquipment` as examples) differ a lot and do not share a common interface, they most likely differ in their appearance. In this case you would need different `DataTemplate`s for each type. This is an example for a `ContentControl`, but it works the same fot `ItemsContol`s with implicit data templates (no `x:Key`, but a `DataType`) that are applied automatically.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Equipment}">
   <ContentControl.Resources>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:Equipment}">
         <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding IsAvailable, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, FallbackValue=DarkGray}" Margin="1"/>
      </DataTemplate>
      <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:OtherEquipment}">
         <Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="DarkGray" Margin="1"/>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ContentControl.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

A workaround for your *specific issue* could be writing a custom, specialized value converter.

```
public class EquipmentAvailabilityToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
   public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      if (value is Equipment equipment)
         return equipment.IsAvailable ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;

      return (Brush)parameter;
   }

   public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   {
      throw new InvalidOperationException();
   }
}
```

```
<Ellipse Width="10" Height="10" Fill="{Binding Equipment, Converter={StaticResource EquipmentAvailabilityToColorConverter}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Brushes.DarkGray}}" Margin="1"/>
```